# Printing on two different printers at different times windows 7 firefox

Tags: windows-7, printing, laser-printer, inkjet-printer

Ok, I am a greeting card maker, and this is what I'm trying to do:  I have two printers.  One is an ink-jet (color, of course).  One is a laser jet that only prints in black.  I need to be able to print a base color layer on the inkjet printer (for the colored elements) and then I need to be able to take that SAME sheet and run it through the laser printer for a detail layer to go on top of the base color design.  The reason being, the detail layer will be foiled with gold foil, and the foiling material will only react with a laser printing. I need these two prints to line up perfectly or at least semi-perfectly.  As of now, it is WAY off... as in my detail layer is way off the mark.

The ink jet is an HP & the laser printer is a Brother.  If there is any additional info needed to assist me, I am happy to provide it.  Thank you!

I'm adding an image to allow you to see what I'm going for -- notice the colored flowers with gold foil accents on top. (this isn't my creation, just an example)[here's a link, it won't let me embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H8LN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Lining the printing up perfectly will prove to be impossible. It all depends on the paper transport in the printers, which never happens twice in exactly the same way - neither on the laser, nor on the inkjet. From the scanned image I can only guess how far the gold layer is shifted. If it's only 2 mm or so then it is probably within the specs of the printer.

Some high-end lasers let you move the image on the page, for the purpose of getting the 2 sides of a duplexed page to line up. If your printer supports that, you can have a play with it and see if it improves things. I do not know of any inkjets that support a similar feature.

What model Brother do you have?